# Is it possible to see a remote ubuntu server throught a gui?

Tags: 13.04, server, kubuntu, remote-desktop

I have some ubuntu (version 13.10) servers which I can access throught ssh.

It is all fine, but I'd like to access them with a gui, so to handle some operations more efficiently.

Of course I'd like to NOT install any desktop environment on the server itself, I'd just like a way to see what there is on that server with a gui on client side...don't know if I explained myself well.

Would it be possible?

I am currently using kubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manage files and folders, you can use sftp:

```
1. Open File Manager and press Ctrl+L
2. Type: sftp://remoteip/
```

If you want to view the remote ubuntu desktop (like teamviewer), you can use remmina:

```
sudo apt-get remmina
```

to install remmina remote desktop client

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the applications you want to manage, some applications have web clients you can use.  `mdadm` and `deluge-d` come to mind.

Otherwise you're best off writing few scripts to handle your common operations. If you set them up right you could execute them from your ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer you want is yes it can.

I would recommend using xrdp/vnc, or teamviewer.